# how to remove font awesome from my page load

Tags: php, wordpress, function, font-awesome, nextgen-gallery

baytalebaa.com
wordpress,
first

1- search for "fontawesome" using inspect

the following link casing my website to slow down by 2 sec 
and i want to remove it .

2- http://baytalebaa.com/?ngg_serve_fontawesome_css=1&ver=4.6.1

it seems that nextgen plugin is calling it , how to stop it ? please help

i have tried the following

wp_dequeue_style( 'fontawesome' );
didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the plugin directly and serve the CDN version of the plugin, or remove the reference all together.

An alternative option is to serve the plugin files directly from CDN and distribute them via Cloudfront or an alternative service if you are not doing so already.

W3 Cache is a great plugin for managing issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code on page load. this might be helpful for you.

```
function remove_unwanted_css(){
wp_dequeue_style(‘font-awesome’, ‘https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css’);
}
add_filter(‘wp_print_styles’, ‘remove_unwanted_css’);
```